# django/python: screen sharing api

Tags: python, django, api

I am looking for a screen sharing functionality api in django/python which allows remote users to view your desktop in real time.

Any recommendations on a library/api to use?

Thanks.

Comment: You ever found out ?

Comment: It was required long time back, not any django specific I used. 

I used bigbluebutton at that time

Answer (score 4):

Django is a web development framework; remote desktop viewing is a client-side task. It may be possible to integrate screen sharing into a web site that is built using Django, but Django itself will likely have no involvement with the "guts" of the task.